# detect change of selectmenu in jquery mobile 1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, select-menu

I am revisiting JQM after not using it for a few versions.

I have a simple selectbox

```
<select name="current-option" id="current-option" class="current-option" data-native-menu="false">
        <option>Select Option</option>
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
    </select>
```

I want to be able to detect a change in this select box and then read it's value. It seems as though typical jquery methods don't work and I dont see an event for this in the api: http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/

Comment: Does it support standard events like onchange?

Comment: No. That is the problem. The 2 answers below work in a normal environment, but not in jQuery mobile 1.4. Once the page is initialized selectmenu actually becomes a button and the select box is hidden. Onchange doesn't trigger.

Comment: The menu itself becomes a button, or each option?

Comment: Alok's answer works but has to be wrapped in an document-ready-function

Answer (score 4):

Ok, you want to know value of option selected after change event occurs; You should do following:--

```
$('#current-option').change(function () {
  var optionSelected = $(this).find('option:selected');
  //var optTextSelected = optionSelected.text();
  var optValueSelected = optionSelected.val();
});
```

I would request you to change name, id and class names for your select tag.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't in a mobile environment, but it using the mobile plugins: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9DQES/)

HTML

```
<select name="current-option" id="current-option" class="current-option" data-native-menu="false">
    <option>Select Option</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
<label id='thelabel'></label>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#current-option').change(function () {
    $('#thelabel').text($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I took at look at the DOM after a select-menu is generated. It looks like the select-menu plugin will create a `div` with an id similar to the id of the `select`; in this case it would be `current-option-listbox`. The children of this `div` consist of several things, including the options. Based on this, I came up with the below solution:

```
var currentValue = ""; // keep track of the selected value

$('.ui-btn-inner', '#current-option-listbox').click(function () {
    if ('a', this).text() !== currentValue) {
        // the value changed - do stuff
        currentValue = $(this).children('a').text();
    }
});
```

This is heavily dependent on the plugin's render method remaining the same, or at the developer maintaining use of the plugin the code was designed around. I believe this will get you what you need.

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9DQES/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The event you need is 'selectmenuchange', jQuery mobile triggers this event for selects instead of 'change'.

It should go like this:

```
    $('#current-option').on('selectmenuchange',function () {
       $('#thelabel').text($(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

normally the code below should work. But i'm not sure. Try please.

```
$('#current-option').change(function () {
   $('#thelabel').text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).